# How to reuse a navigation bar across different .html pages with CSS and JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, parceljs

In total, I have 3 pages: `index.html`, `sketch.html` and `user-profile.html`.

All of them have the same navbar (I just copied and pasted the `nav` element for now), but I now realize that this is not the best idea.

The navbar has its position on the screen (HTML), the styling (CSS) and the login and register functionality (Javascript). How would I go about combining these for three different pages?

Since I am using a module bundler (Parcel.js), I was thinking of creating a `.js` and `.css` for EACH page. So for example the folder `index` will have:

`index.css` -> will import the necessary elements, example (pseudo-code): `import "../styles/navbar.css"`

`index.js` -> will import the necessary scripting for logging and registering, example: `require("..scripts/sessions.js");`

`index.html` -> will import those two files

... and do the same for each page.

But... is that really necessary? Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Are you trying to avoid using any service side language to accomplish this? If so, you can try to create the nav bar dynamically with JavaScript linked to each page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, there's not an easy way to do this with vanilla Javascript. You basically have to either create the navbar using JS, which can then be imported to each page, or you have to copy and paste it.

The industry solution to this problem is to use React, Vue or Angular, all technologies which allow you to create and reuse JSX 'components'. In other words, in React, you could create a navbar component, which could easily be imported in any 'page' of the website. But with vanilla HTML/Javascript, it's really not an option.

Answer (score 1):

There is a dirty-but-working vanilla JS hack:

```
async function includeHTML() {
  const includes = document.getElementsByTagName('include');
  [].forEach.call(includes, include => {
    let filePath = include.getAttribute('src');
    fetch(filePath).then((file) => {
      file.text().then((content) => {
        include.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', content);
        include.remove();
      });
    });
  });
};
```

Now, you can create element like this: `<include src="navbar.html"></include>`

Just run the function. If you add some javascript functionality, use Promises so that your code executes *after* this function.

```
includeHTML()
```